# rJava import not working in airflow

Tags: r, airflow, rjava, java-home

I am trying to schedule some r script in airflow, I am using rJava library in my script. rJava and xlsx is working fine in R terminal, but not in airflow environment. I am getting this error,

```
libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In my `~/.bashrc` file,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

In my `~/.profile` file,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar

export HADOOP_HOME='/home/ubuntu/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/hadoop-2.7.4'
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

In my `/etc/environment`,

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar";
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server";
```

Also, I tried to add this line in the top of my R script before importing rJava,

```
system('export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar')
system('export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server')
```

Even then I keep getting libjvm.so file missing error. But I can see that file in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server`

When I checked the log in airflow, the dag is running the script in `Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmp7Ws3X2//tmp/airflowtmp7Ws3X2/nz-property-report6vTyGr`

I think it is not picking the environment variables, getting this error,

```
Loading required package: xlsx
[2018-08-09 21:39:23,755] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-09 21:39:23,755] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
[2018-08-09 21:39:23,755] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-09 21:39:23,755] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
[2018-08-09 21:39:23,755] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-09 21:39:23,755] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
[2018-08-09 21:39:23,755] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-09 21:39:23,755] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - error: unable to load shared object '/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
[2018-08-09 21:39:23,756] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-09 21:39:23,755] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me with using rJava in my R script in airflow?

EDIT: As requested, here is my DAG script,

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
#from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='property_report',
    schedule_interval=None,
)

task = BashOperator(
    task_id='report',
    dag=dag,
    bash_command="Rscript /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/scripts/r-scripts/recreate_lastmonthreport_from_snapshotdata.R",
    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    owner='airflow')
```

Comment: Can you post the operator from your DAG triggering your script?  Also can you check your airflow.cfg for `default_impersonation` and see if that is set to anything

Comment: Thanks for your comment, updated the DAG here. And the `default_impersonation ` in airflow.cfg has no values assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help anyone looking for an answer for this. I just had to `source ~/.bashrc` in both screens running web server and scheduler separately and restart them. It picked up the env variables fine.